# python regex: Getting the string in the next line after a given string

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm working on python script that will extract some words. These words are from a larger text and must be after a given strings and some lines.

Like this:
Country --> This is the word I know
Judecatoria X/Tribunalul X/Judecatoria Sectorului X --> One of these words are present in the text, however I do not know which of them and I want regex to matched it.

```
import re

text:"""Country  
     Judecatoria Sectorului X"""

#pattern = this is what I am looking for
```

expected result:['Judecatoria Sectorului X']

Thank you very much!

Comment: You have mentioned twice what your text is. So its hard to know what the text string is ? Is it the one in your code or the one you mention in description above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but, if you want to find what is in next line after `Country`, this should do it:

```
import re
text = """Country  
     Judecatoria Sectorului X"""
result = re.search('Country\s*\n\s*(.*)\s*', text).group(1)
print(result)
```

If `Country` is just an example and it might be one of many words, change `Country` to `(?:Country|Something else|Yet another one)`

Comment: Thank you for you answer. For my own edification can you tell me the logic behind the expresion. I would be forever thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
>>> import re
>>> text = """Country  
...      Judecatoria Sectorului X"""

>>> [x.strip() for x in re.findall("\n.*", text)]
['Judecatoria Sectorului X']
```